# Combine OUTPUT inserted.id with value from selected row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Running `SQL Server 2014`. How can I insert multiple rows from a table and combine the inserted data with the new IDs?

Let's look at a stripped-down example!

```
DECLARE @Old TABLE 
(
    [ID] [int] PRIMARY KEY,
    [Data] [int] NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @New TABLE
(
    [ID] [int] PRIMARY KEY,
    [OtherID] [int] NULL
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Data])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID], [@Old].[ID] /* <--- not supported :( */ INTO @New
SELECT [Data]
FROM @Old
```

I need to combine the inserted IDs with the data that is being inserted. Can I assume that the inserted rows are in the same order as the selected rows? (I will not be able to join on `[Data]` after the insert operation.)

### Update

The following seems like a possible solution, but I cannot find proof that it works. Is it guaranteed to work?

```
DECLARE @Old TABLE 
(
    [RowID] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, -- Guaranteed insert order?     
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Data] [int] NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @New TABLE
(
    [RowID] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, -- Guaranteed insert order? 
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OtherID] [int] NULL
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Data])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @New
SELECT [Data]
FROM @Old
ORDER BY [RowID]
```

The trick here is to use a separate `identity` column and `ORDER BY` for the selected rows, and then **joining on** `RowID`.

Comment: When You INSERT, You'd use only inserted table. This means You have to add artificial field in @New table.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can (ab)use [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) with `OUTPUT` clause.

`MERGE` can `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` rows. In our case we need only to `INSERT`. 
1=0 is always false, so the `NOT MATCHED BY TARGET` part is always executed. 
In general, there could be other branches, see docs. 
`WHEN MATCHED` is usually used to `UPDATE`; 
`WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` is usually used to `DELETE`, but we don't need them here.

This convoluted form of `MERGE` is equivalent to simple `INSERT`, 
but unlike simple `INSERT` its `OUTPUT` clause allows to refer to the columns that we need. 
It allows to retrieve columns from both source and destination tables thus saving a mapping between old and new IDs.

```
MERGE INTO [dbo].[Test]
USING
(
    SELECT [Data]
    FROM @Old AS O
) AS Src
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT ([Data])
VALUES (Src.[Data])
OUTPUT Src.ID AS OldID, inserted.ID AS NewID
INTO @New(ID, [OtherID])
;
```

---

Regarding your update and relying on the order of generated `IDENTITY` values.

In the simple case, when `[dbo].[Test]` has `IDENTITY` column, then `INSERT` with `ORDER BY` **will** guarantee that the generated `IDENTITY` values would be in the specified order. See point 4 in [Ordering guarantees in SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/07/20/441053.aspx). Mind you, it doesn't guarantee the physical order of inserted rows, but it guarantees the order in which `IDENTITY` values are generated.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Data])
SELECT [Data]
FROM @Old
ORDER BY [RowID]
```

But, when you use the `OUTPUT` clause:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test] ([Data])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @New
SELECT [Data]
FROM @Old
ORDER BY [RowID]
```

the rows in the `OUTPUT` stream are not ordered. At least, strictly speaking, `ORDER BY` in the query applies to the primary `INSERT` operation, but there is nothing there that says what is the order of the `OUTPUT`. So, I would not try to rely on that. Either use `MERGE` or add an extra column to store the mapping between IDs explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, the `OUTPUT` clause is not designed to output something not going into the target table (or coming from the table in the case of an `update`).

If you modify `Data` to have a dummy column for the old id, then you can output it.

In fact, if the table is not large, you could consider adding the column for the insert and then dropping it afterwards.

Comment: Interesting idea. Unfortunately, the table is quite large. Would it be possible to join `@New` and `@Old` on the row number if we add `ORDER BY [@Old].[ID]`?

Comment: @l33t . . . My guess is that would work, if you have an identity column in `@New`.  I'm not sure this is documented anywhere, but an identity column in `test` should respect the ordering.  I imagine the same is true for the `output` clause.

Comment: Please see my update. Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, in SQL Server `MERGE` supports columns from both source and destination tables in the `OUTPUT` clause. See my answer.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov . . . That seems like a better approach.