# Get ID of inserted & Selected row after multiple insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query running in loop which I am trying to optimize as this

```
INSERT INTO myTable (col1, col2, col3)
OUTPUT inserted.id, SOURCE_ROW_ID_NEEDED_HERE
    SELECT col1, col2, col3 
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE col2 = 20 --any value
```

My problem is : col2 = 20 can have N number of rows which get inserted, I need the id of the source row for the new record. For example say there are 3 rows for col2 = 20 and id of them are 11,12,15. The new inserted ID are say 150,151,152.

I would need

```
11  150
12  151
15  152
```

Comment: You can only put columns in `output` that are in the records being inserted into the new table.  So if the `id` is being inserted, you can include it in the output.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks. I reckon that would be the case. Any hack to achieve desired result?

Comment: You can probably do it with a merge statement

Comment: does the source table have an id column?  If so, include it in the insert statement and output it via the output clause

Comment: You might be able to use this existing answer and go from there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687950/combine-output-inserted-id-with-value-from-selected-row

Comment: @user1443098, yes it has. But it is an Identity key. I thought this was clear with the sql I posted :)

Comment: Clear enough!  So insert that key in the target table, then you have it,

Comment: Source & target tables are same. I can not insert into identity column.

Comment: OK -- so I'm missing the point of this.  Why are you re-inserting rows in the table?  (and, you could add a new column to the table to hold the source id number)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like

```
CREATE TABLE T1(
  Col1 INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
  Col2 INT,
  Col3 INT
);

CREATE TABLE T2(
  Col1 INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
  Col2 INT,
  Col3 INT
);

INSERT INTO T2(Col2, Col3) VALUES
(11,  150),
(12,  151),
(15,  152);

DECLARE @TT TABLE (ID INT, Col2 INT);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT T1 ON;

INSERT INTO T1 (Col1, Col2, Col3)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Col1,
       INSERTED.Col2
INTO @TT (ID, Col2)
SELECT Col1,
       Col2,
       Col3
FROM T2;

SELECT *
FROM @TT;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT T1 OFF;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3ef791dfffbc32c25490b7d98f624ff8)**