# How to get inserted NewSequentialId value when doing multiple inserts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, newsequentialid

Does SQL Server guarantee that NewSequentialId() will be called for each row in the order specified by the ORDER BY clause of an INSERT statement?

The goal is to take a list of objects in C#, each of which represents a row to be inserted in a table, and insert them into a table fairly quickly.

What I'm trying to do is insert the rows into a temporary table using SqlBulkCopy, then insert the rows from the temp table into a table that uses NewSequentialId(), then retrieve the new IDs in a way that they can be sorted in the same order as the list of objects in C#, so that the IDs can be attached to each corresponding object in C#.

I'm using SQL Server 2016 and this is the target table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
    SomeNonUniqueValue NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

First I use SqlBulkCopy to insert rows into this temp table. The RowOrder columns contains an integer generated in the application. RowOrder is the order I need the generated IDs to be returned in. In the application, RowOrder is the index of each C# object in the list.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTableStaging
(
    RowOrder INT NOT NULL,
    SomeNonUniqueValue NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Then I run this SQL to take the rows from #MyTableStaging, insert them into MyTable and retrieve the inserted IDs.

```
DECLARE @MyTableOutput TABLE
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (SomeNonUniqueValue)
OUTPUT Inserted.Id INTO @MyTableOutput(Id)
SELECT SomeNonUniqueValue 
FROM #MyTableStaging
ORDER BY RowOrder

SELECT Id FROM @MyTableOutput ORDER BY Id
```

In all my testing this works. However, I recently found out that the order in which rows are inserted into the table specified in the OUTPUT clause is not always the same as the order specified by the ORDER BY in the INSERT statement (I found this because the original design of this system was to use an identity in #MyTableStaging, and rather than ordering by #MyTableStaging.Id I was ordering by the identity column).

I know that SQL Server guarantees that identity values are generated in the order specified in the ORDER BY clause of an INSERT statement (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#limitations-and-restrictions):

> INSERT queries that use SELECT with ORDER BY to populate rows
>   guarantees how identity values are computed but not the order in which
>   the rows are inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (and likely most efficient) way would be to insert into the target `MyTable` table directly without the intermediate staging table. I'd use a table-valued-parameter to pass the table of values into your stored procedure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters

---

If you really want to use the staging table, you can't rely on the order of rows returned by the `OUTPUT` clause. You need to store the explicit mapping between the `#MyTableStaging.RowOrder` and the generated `MyTable.Id`. When you use `OUTPUT` clause in a simple `INSERT` statement you can't include columns from the source table into the output. There is a workaround. You can use [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) instead of `INSERT` and `OUTPUT` clause of the `MERGE` statement allows columns from source table.

See very similar question [Combine OUTPUT inserted.id with value from selected row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687950/combine-output-inserted-id-with-value-from-selected-row)

`MERGE` can `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` rows. In our case we need only to `INSERT`. 
`1=0` is always false, so the `NOT MATCHED BY TARGET` part is always executed. 
In general, there could be other branches, see docs. 
`WHEN MATCHED` is usually used to `UPDATE`; 
`WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` is usually used to `DELETE`, but we don't need them here.

This convoluted form of `MERGE` is equivalent to simple `INSERT`, 
but unlike simple `INSERT` its `OUTPUT` clause allows to refer to the columns that we need. 
It allows to retrieve columns from both source and destination tables thus saving a mapping between old and new IDs.

```
DECLARE @MyTableOutput TABLE
(
    OldRowOrder int NOT NULL
    ,NewID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
);


MERGE INTO dbo.MyTable
USING
(
    SELECT RowOrder, SomeNonUniqueValue
    FROM #MyTableStaging
) AS Src
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (SomeNonUniqueValue)
VALUES (Src.SomeNonUniqueValue)
OUTPUT Src.RowOrder AS OldRowOrder, inserted.ID AS NewID
INTO @MyTableOutput(OldRowOrder, NewID)
;
```

---

If your DBA is so afraid of `MERGE` you don't have to use it. It will be less efficient, though.

Simply insert all rows.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (SomeNonUniqueValue)
SELECT SomeNonUniqueValue 
FROM #MyTableStaging
;
```

We don't care about the order.

If `SomeNonUniqueValue` were unique, you could just join on this column to map `RowOrder` to `Id`. Since these values are not unique, we'll need an extra step and generate unique row numbers for joining.

```
WITH
CTE_Dst
AS
(

    SELECT
        Id
        ,SomeNonUniqueValue
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeNonUniqueValue) AS rn
    FROM dbo.MyTable
)
,CTE_Src
AS
(

    SELECT
        RowOrder
        ,SomeNonUniqueValue
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeNonUniqueValue) AS rn
    FROM #MyTableStaging
)
SELECT
    CTE_Dst.Id
    ,CTE_Src.RowOrder
FROM
    CTE_Dst
    INNER JOIN CTE_Src ON CTE_Src.rn = CTE_Dst.rn
;
```

If you have, say, three rows with the same `SomeNonUniqueValue` it doesn't really matter how you map these rows together, because `SomeNonUniqueValue` is the same.

Example:

```
#MyTableStaging
+----------+--------------------+
| RowOrder | SomeNonUniqueValue |
+----------+--------------------+
|        1 | qwerty             |
|        2 | qwerty             |
|        3 | qwerty             |
|        4 | asdf               |
|        5 | asdf               |
+----------+--------------------+

MyTable
+----+--------------------+
| ID | SomeNonUniqueValue |
+----+--------------------+
| A  | qwerty             |
| B  | qwerty             |
| C  | qwerty             |
| D  | asdf               |
| E  | asdf               |
+----+--------------------+
```

You can map them like this:

```
+----------+----+--------------------+
| RowOrder | ID | SomeNonUniqueValue |
+----------+----+--------------------+
|        1 | A  | qwerty             |
|        2 | B  | qwerty             |
|        3 | C  | qwerty             |
|        4 | D  | asdf               |
|        5 | E  | asdf               |
+----------+----+--------------------+
```

Or, you can map them like this:

```
+----------+----+--------------------+
| RowOrder | ID | SomeNonUniqueValue |
+----------+----+--------------------+
|        1 | B  | qwerty             |
|        2 | C  | qwerty             |
|        3 | A  | qwerty             |
|        4 | E  | asdf               |
|        5 | D  | asdf               |
+----------+----+--------------------+
```

It is still a valid mapping, because all three values of `qwerty` are the same. Neither of these mapping is "more correct" than another.

Obviously, if your `MyTable` wasn't empty before the `INSERT`, you need to select new rows only.

Comment: Thanks. About the idea of using a tvp: I don't understand how using a tvp as the source data would solve the output ordering problem. It seems to me like doing the insert from a tvp would produce the same ordering problem as doing the insert from a temp table. If you just mean that using a tvp would be more efficient than using a temp table, I think you're probably right.

Comment: Using a tvp is definitely a good idea, the reason I'm not using a tvp is because in actuality I'm using this process for a few hundred different tables and generating the SQL text dynamically in C#, so I'd either have to manually manage all the UDT table types needed for the tvp's or dynamically generate the table types, and since I didn't want to give the service account that will run this process enough permissions to create a udt, I used a temp table.

Comment: I think your MERGE statement idea is probably the best solution that can be found for this problem. I'm going to wait a few days to see what other solutions people have and then I'll mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks for your help! I'm hesitant to use MERGE because I've heard bad things about it and my DBA has actually blanket banned us from using MERGE, but I can't imagine that using it like this would cause problems. This is what my DBA sent us when he implemented the ban a few months ago: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: 1) Yes, I was thinking of using TVP without temp table. 2) I've been using MERGE in SQL Server 2008 in production. The bugs listed in that article are for quite special cases. 3) You don't have to use MERGE, actually, if your DBA is so afraid of it. You can map RowOrder to ID by joining on `SomeNonUniqueValue`, but `OUTPUT` clause is very straight-forward.